# Draw a circle with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geometry

Maybe it is a silly question, but I couldn't find the answer in the handbook of ggplot2 nor with "aunt" google...

How do I plot a circle with ggplot2 as an additional layer if I have a middle point and a diameter?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Aunt Google was more responsive to me. [This](http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/7f4238b5658e85bb) might be of some help.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

A newer, better option leverages an extension package called [ggforce](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggforce) that defines an explicity `geom_circle`.

But for posterity's sake, here's a simple circle function:

```
circleFun <- function(center = c(0,0),diameter = 1, npoints = 100){
    r = diameter / 2
    tt <- seq(0,2*pi,length.out = npoints)
    xx <- center[1] + r * cos(tt)
    yy <- center[2] + r * sin(tt)
    return(data.frame(x = xx, y = yy))
}
```

And a demonstration of it's use:

```
dat <- circleFun(c(1,-1),2.3,npoints = 100)
#geom_path will do open circles, geom_polygon will do filled circles
ggplot(dat,aes(x,y)) + geom_path()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joran, that was what I'm looking for... I'm just wondering, that you have to go with the function to realize that in ggplot. If I remember it correctly, plot have a build in function for that. But this plots just look way nicer ;-)

Comment: @Dominik - Indeed, there is `grid.circle`, but to make that work will require some knowledge of the `grid` system.

Answer (score 26):

If the purpose is only to annotate a circle, you can simply use annotate with geometry "path". No need to create a data frame or function:

```
#g is your plot
#r, xc, yc are the radius and center coordinates

g<-g+annotate("path",
   x=xc+r*cos(seq(0,2*pi,length.out=100)),
   y=yc+r*sin(seq(0,2*pi,length.out=100)))
```

Answer (score 17):

Hi the following code from [ggplot2 Google](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/8Qe1Ew6q4tQ) group may be useful:

```
dat = data.frame(x=runif(1), y=runif(1))
ggplot() + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,1)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1))+
geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y), data=dat, size=50, shape=1, color="gold4")
```

Which Produces:
[image]

I hope it gets you started in hacking up custom examples for your purpose.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think this method addresses the OP's question, which was how to draw a circle *given a center and diameter*. It will be very tough to get the correct diameter using the size aesthetic.

Comment: Ya I agree, it was just a pointer in the right direction not a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks for that hint Neo_me, but the way Joran posted fits better for my needs.

Comment: Great to see this, this was more what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: The reason why `shape=1` is needed is that the default shape for `geom_point` is shape 19 where the fill color and stroke color cannot be controlled separately (so `fill=alpha("black",0)` doesn't work), but with `shape=1` it's possible to use different fill and stroke colors and the default fill color is transparent.

Answer (score 14):

with `ggplot2 >= 0.9` you can also do

```
library(grid)
qplot(1:10, 1:10, geom="blank") +
  annotation_custom(grob=circleGrob(r=unit(1,"npc")), xmin=2, xmax=4, ymin=4, ymax=6)
```

Comment: This changes size with the size of the canvas.

Answer (score 11):

For posterity's sake here is a more flexible circle solution using annotate and geom_ribbon that supports fill, color, alpha, and size.

```
gg_circle <- function(r, xc, yc, color="black", fill=NA, ...) {
    x <- xc + r*cos(seq(0, pi, length.out=100))
    ymax <- yc + r*sin(seq(0, pi, length.out=100))
    ymin <- yc + r*sin(seq(0, -pi, length.out=100))
    annotate("ribbon", x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, color=color, fill=fill, ...)
}
square <- ggplot(data.frame(x=0:1, y=0:1), aes(x=x, y=y))
square + gg_circle(r=0.25, xc=0.5, yc=0.5)
square + gg_circle(r=0.25, xc=0.5, yc=0.5, color="blue", fill="red", alpha=0.2)
```

Answer (score 5):

Also try this,

```
 ggplot() + geom_rect(aes(xmin=-1,ymin=-1,xmax=1,ymax=1), fill=NA) + coord_polar()
```

The point being, a circle in some coordinates system is often not a circle in others, unless you use geom_point. You might want to ensure an aspect ratio of 1 with cartesian coordinates.

Comment: What I want to plot is an importance horizon on a scatter plot. For this jorans solution seems to be the best way. But thanks a lot for your hint as well.