# R: plot circle with radius = 1 and angle 0-2pi in polar -coordinates?

Tags: r, plot

I found the plotrix package in R but cannot yet find how to do this simple circle in R. Basically, how can I do a polar-plot with radius of 1 and 0:360 angles in degree, generating a circle?

**Example**

$$r\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\left(\frac{3\theta}{2\pi}-\left\lfloor\frac{3\theta}{2\pi}\right\rfloor\right) -\frac{\pi}{3}\right) = 1$$

**Perhaps related**

1. Trying to plot the above function, more [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/123548/5902), the LaTex with this hack [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3297/5902) visible.
2. [Draw a circle with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862742/draw-a-circle-with-ggplot2)
3. [Regular polygons in polar coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/41954/5902)

Answer (score 7):

You can also make circles using geometry

```
circle <- function(x, y, rad = 1, nvert = 500, ...){
    rads <- seq(0,2*pi,length.out = nvert)
    xcoords <- cos(rads) * rad + x
    ycoords <- sin(rads) * rad + y
    polygon(xcoords, ycoords, ...)
}

# asp = 1 due to Hans' comment below- wouldn't let me leave a comment just saying 'thanks'
plot(-5:5, type="n", xlim = c(-5,5), ylim = c(-5,5), asp = 1)
circle(0,0,4)
circle(-1.5,1.5,.5)
circle(1.5,1.5,.5)
circle(0,0,1)
segments(-2,-2,2,-2)
```

Comment: You'd better not forget the aspect ratio, `asp = 1`, when calling the plot command to see that it's really a circle.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily get polar coordinate graphs in ggplot2.

[From the ggplot2 website:](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/coord_polar.html)

```
library(ggplot2)    

cxc <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl))) + 
           geom_bar(width = 1, colour = "black") 

cxc <- cxc + coord_polar()

print(cxc)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can do very nice circular statistics with package [circular](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/circular/index.html). Below is one of examples from the package:

```
require(circular)
x <- circular(runif(50, 0, 2*pi))
rose.diag(x, bins = 18, main = 'Uniform Data',col=2)
points(x)
```

[image]