# Draw circle in date axis with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geometry

Now I draw plot with ggplot2.

I want to draw circle in my plot.

So I searched it and found the solutions.

[Draw a circle with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862742/draw-a-circle-with-ggplot2)

However I can't use this solution, because my plot's x axis is Date format.

```
my_plot <- qplot(Day, value, data = target_data_melt, shape = variable, colour = variable, geom="line")
my_plot <- my_plot + scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m"))
```

How can I draw a circle in my plot?

Is there any way to draw a circle in Date axis?

---

target_data_melt looks like this.

> ```
>       Day  variable       value
> ```
>
> 1   2010-10-01 231 0.007009346
>
> 2   2010-10-03 231 0.005204835
>
> 3   2010-10-05 231 0.006214004

Comment: can you dput your target_data_melt or at least  a sample?

Comment: Thanks for commenting my question.
taget_data_melt look like this.

           Day  variable       value
1   2010-10-01 231 0.007009346
2   2010-10-03 231 0.005204835
3   2010-10-05 231 0.006214004

So I used @Alexander Vos de Wael solution and fixed it a little bit.^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt the code from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6863490/1849317) you provided to format the x-coordinate as Date:

```
require("date")

circle <- function(center_Date = as.Date("2012-11-24"), 
                   center_y = 0, 
                   r.x = 100,
                   r.y = 100,
                   npoints = 100) {
  cycle <- seq(0,2*pi,length.out = npoints)
  xx <- center_Date + r.x * cos(cycle)
  yy <- center_y + r.y * sin(cycle)
  return(data.frame(x = xx, y = yy))
}
```

And a demonstration:

```
df <- circle()
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_path()
plot(plot)
```

Example image (with an adjusted date and y-center) [here](http://pasteboard.s3.amazonaws.com/images/14nbKfu4.png).

You'll have to set the r.x and r.y properly to get a perfect circle (rather than an oval). What these should be depends on the scales you use in your plots.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Now I can draw circles in my plot!
One interesting point is y axis is continuous one, so r.x and r.y scale is different!. So it's hard to draw exact circle, not ellipse.