# Draw circles on dotplot to mark optimal regions in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have a point plot with power plants that have the properties x and y. The best power plants are those were x and y are both high. I now want to visualize which regions of my plot are desirable and less desirable for a power plant to be in

What i need to produce is something like this:
[image]

Any ideas? i tried drawing huge dots with geom_point but they change size depending on the export resolution of my plot I also tried drawing circles like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862742/draw-a-circle-with-ggplot2) but ggplot doesn't draw the circles correctly if parts of it fall outside the actual plot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using @joran's circle function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862742/draw-a-circle-with-ggplot2), this seems to work:

```
# prepare data for circles
green <- circleFun(center = c(5, 5), diameter = 1.5, npoints = 100)
yellow <- circleFun(center = c(5, 5), diameter = 3, npoints = 100)
orange <- circleFun(center = c(5, 5), diameter = 4.5, npoints = 100)
red <- circleFun(center = c(5, 5), diameter = 6, npoints = 100)

dat <- rbind(green, yellow, orange, red)

# specify levels to get the order of colours right,
# and set the plotting order from large (red) to small (green) circle
dat$fill <- factor(rep(c("green", "yellow", "orange", "red"), each = 100),
                   levels = rev(c("green", "yellow", "orange", "red")))

# dummy data for points
dat2 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100, mean = 3), y = rnorm(100, mean = 3))

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = fill)) +
  geom_point(data = dat2, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 5), ylim = c(0, 5)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = rev(c("green", "yellow", "orange", "red")))
```

[image]
**Things that did not work so well:**
For some reason circles are distorted when (1) the legend is turned off using `theme(legend.position = "none")`, and (2) when `scale_fill_identity()` is used, instead of `scale_fill_manual()`, to pick colours from 'fill' variable in 'dat'. I have no clue why.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried something similar but just couldn't get it to work

Comment: Glad to help! Yes, I tried some different ways but the whole set-up seems a bit shaky. For example, when I tried `scale_fill_identity()` to use the fill variable in `dat`, the circles got distorted. And the strange legend thing as I mentioned in my answer. Well, well, hope it is good enough for your purpose!