# Overlay a circle on a scatter plot in R

Tags: r

I'm using this link to create the circle: [Draw a circle with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862742/draw-a-circle-with-ggplot2)

However, when I try to add my next *ggplot* which uses data from a CSV, I get two separate graphs. I'd like to have the circle overlay the scatterplot.

```
ggplot(CSV1, aes(x= Pos.X..µm., y = Pos.Y..µm.)) +
    geom_point() 

ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) + geom_path()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data. Show the code you tried. Perhaps we can point out the problem.

Comment: ggplot(CSV1, aes(x= Pos.X..µm., y = Pos.Y..µm. )) + geom_point()

ggplot(dat,aes(x,y)) + geom_path()

Comment: You should edit that into your question rather than leaving as a comment.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for the tip, I'm new to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to combine it into a single object.

```
ggplot(CSV1, aes(x= Pos.X..µm., y = Pos.Y..µm.)) +
    geom_point()  +
    geom_path(aes(x,y), data=dat)
```

Comment: It's still only displaying the scatter plot.

Comment: Well then you need to post sample data so we can see what's actually in `CSV1` and `dat` so we can test it ourselves.

Comment: I'm simply reading X & Y position from the .csv but I'd like to overlay a circle. Any suggestions on how to do that? Maybe, there's a better approach than the code I found on the internet. Thanks for your help!