# Finding the x value of a curve given f(x) in R?

Tags: r, function, math, optimization, linear-algebra

I was wondering why I can't find the other existing value of `x` whose `f(x)` equals the `f(.6)`?

In other words, I'm wondering how to find the `x` value of the point indicated by the red X in the *picture below*?

**Here is what I have tried without success:**

```
source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/i/master/ii.r") # source the function

f <- function(x, n.pred = 5, N = 100, conf.level = .95){ 
  ci <- R2.ci(R2 = x, n.pred = n.pred, N = N, conf.level = conf.level)  # The objective function
  ci$upper - ci$lower
}

curve(f, panel.f = abline(v = .6, h = f(.6), col = 2, lty = c(2, 1)))  # curve the function

uniroot(function(x) f(.6) - f(x), c(0, 1))[[1]]  # find the requested 'x' value

`Error: f() values at end points not of opposite sign`
```

[image]

Comment: are you looking for [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087814/how-to-find-an-intersection-of-curve-and-circle/50089155#50089155)

Comment: I cant run your code. That is why I directed you to that

Comment: uniroot just returns one root. and you need be on both side of the intersection with that function. Rather than using `c(0,1)` as the range, run it writce with `c(0,.5)` and `c(.5,1)`

Comment: `Error in peta2F(peta, df1, df2) : could not find function "peta2F" `

Comment: Am sorry still experiencing the same error

Comment: still more errors:`Error in peta2ncp(P.eta.sq, N) : could not find function "peta2ncp"`

Comment: What's to say there are only two? "Find every intersection of arbitrary functions" isn't really a well defined mathematical numeric optimization problem. Maybe you want an analytic solution instead, but R is not going to help much there.

Comment: if you are using uniroot then the interval should be c(0,0.4) will give you the answer

Comment: Maybe this question would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519431/finding-point-of-intersection-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 abline(v=uniroot(function(x) f(.6) - f(x), c(0, 0.4))[[1]])
```

[image]