# How to add mile zones to R density plot?

Tags: r

I am plotting some points that correspond to ZIP codes on a US map. I want to have some sort of circle added to certain cities on the US map that will correspond to a zone with a certain amount of miles. For example, if I am looking at Los Angeles, I would want to add a faded circle on top to show a 50 mile radius around Los Angeles. Then I would want another circle on top of the previous one to show 51-150 mile radius around the city, and so on.

I am using ggplot2 package. I tried entering the ZIP code and/or the long/lat as a separate point but it's not working and I am kind of stumped.

```
ggplot(data1, aes(longitude, latitude)) +
geom_polygon(
data = us,
aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
color = 'black',
fill = "gray",
alpha = .35
) + theme_bw()+
geom_point(aes(color = count), size = .3, alpha = .25) +
xlim(-125,-65) + ylim(20, 50) + ggtitle("Density Map of Member Order ZIP 
Codes") +
xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude")
```

*** This produces a plot of the US with many points corresponding to ZIP codes.

No error messages, just stumped on how to proceed and what to try next.

Comment: To draw a circle in ggplot2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862742/draw-a-circle-with-ggplot2

Comment: Didn't help....

Comment: How about this one: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119736/ggmap-create-circle-symbol-where-radius-represents-distance-miles-or-km

Comment: More circles on ggplot2: https://blog.dominodatalab.com/geographic-visualization-with-rs-ggmaps/

Comment: Do you even google bro?

Comment: I've been googling it but I can't find a specific one to fit my situation. That's why I'm looking for someone with expertise. Thanks for trying to help though