# Draw circle using reference points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset `head` that contains two variables `x` and `y` that represent points in the contourn of a circle. I try to draw the circle using this code

```
ggplot(head, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_line()
```

However, the plot I get is this one [image]

Could you help me to fix this? I really need to use those points. Thanks.

Comment: can you provide the data please?

Comment: you want `geom_path`. probably a dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862742/draw-a-circle-with-ggplot2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using geom_path. It connects observations in data order
geom_line connect observations ordered by x value.

If your data is not ordered ok, you can order it by computing angle

```
head <- head %>% mutate(r = atan2(y, x)) %>% arrange(r)
```